# How to add a method that returns the apartments of a specific house by house Id and make it available at "/api/house/{houseId}/apartments"

Tags: asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

Apartment model

```
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
    public int FloorNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumberofRooms { get; set; }
    public int NumberofResidents { get; set; }
    public decimal FullArea { get; set; }
    public decimal LivingSpace { get; set; }
    public long HouseId { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
```

House model

```
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Apartment> Apartments { get; set; }
```

I understand that in order for it to be available at "/api/house/{houseId}/apartments" you need to add [Route], right?
But I don’t fully understand how to make it return the apartments of a specific house by the Id of the house. And in which controller this method should be located?

```
[Route("/api/house/{houseId}/apartments")]
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Apartment>> GetApartment(long id)
{
  var HouseId= await _context.Apartments.FindAsync(id);

  if (HouseId == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }

  return HouseId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your controller could look like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class HouseController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet("{houseId}/apartments")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Apartment>>> GetApartments(int houseId)
    {
        var house = await _context.Houses
            .Include(house => house.Apartments)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(house => house.Id == houseId);

        if (house == null)
        {
            // the house with Id=houseId does not exist so we return NotFound
            return NotFound();
        }

        // the house was found so return its apartments
        return house.Apartments.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I has this error - **Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TaskTwo.Models.Apartment>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TaskTwo.Models.Apartment>>** everything looks right or don't see the problem?

Comment: Change last line to `return house.Apartments.ToList();`, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your api as below:

```
[Route("/api/house/{houseId}/apartments")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<Apartment> GetApartment(int houseId)
        {  
            return Ok();
        }
```

You could pass the houseid to controller now,
And you could try the below codes in controller:

```
var targetapartments= await _context.Apartments.Where(x.HouseId==houseId).ToList();
```